# Opera 19 FPS mini window

Tags: opera, fps

Opera 19 has a very irritating black colored mini-window in top right corner that displays FPS. It obstructs some important part of a web page.

How to remove it ?

Currently I am on 19.0.1326.59 , x64 Windows.

Comment: Opera does _not_ have this window by default, and I've been unable to find any extension or opera:config setting that would do this. Are you sure this isn't some app you've installed independently of your browser? Can you right-click on it and do "Inspect element"?

Comment: @aaamos yeah i am sure, this is not due to any third party app or extension. It wasn't in opera 18, either. I also tried opera:flags, besides :config .  "inspect element" shouldnot matter, because the window also shows up on the start page, and i cannot do that there.    here is a screenshot, look at the top right corner of the image : http://www.shareimages.com/image.php?76426-pJeWmpakk6ClnJyVmKs-screenshot_7.jpg .

Comment: Well, if you tried `opera:flags`, especially if you searched for "fps", you should've seen the option "FPS counter". I just turned this on and it looks exactly like what you describe. So disable it and restart Opera. I hope you're suitably embarrassed. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature you have managed to turn on somehow. Open debugger (Ctrl-Shift-I), select "Rendering" (to the right of Console), and un-check "Show FPS meter".

(Btw, even if FPS is showing, all features below works fine tru it)